# Parking function problem

Tags: graph-theory

> Problem: Let $n \leq m \leq 2n$. Find the number of all parking functions on $[n]$ so that $\sum_{i=1}^n f(i)=m$.

Background:

> Background: A shopping center has n parking spots along a one-way street. One morning, exactly n cars will arrive at the shopping center at various times. Once a car is parked, it does not leave before all other cars arrive. Each of the cars has a favorite parking spot, and a rather short-sighted strategy about it. namely,, each car first goes to its favorite spot. If it is free, the car will take it; if it is not, it will go to the next spot. Then, if the next spot is not free, the car will go to the next spot, and so on, until it finds a free spot. If no spots are free after (and including) the favorite spot of a car, then that car will not have a spot, and we will say that the parking process was unsuccessful. If each car finds a spot, then we will say that the parking process was successful.
> Denote the set of the n cars by the lements of $[n]$, and denote the n parking spots in the order they follow along the one-way street, also by the lements of $[n]$. Let $f(i)$ be the favorite spot of car $i$, then $f:[n] \rightarrow [n]$ is a function. If the parking procesudre i successful, say f is a parking function on $[n]$.

Some results I am thinking about:

> Lemma: The function $f:[n] \rightarrow [n]$ is a parking function iff for all $k \in [n]$, there are at most k values $i \in [n]$ so that $f(i) \geq n-k+1$.
>
> Theorem: For all positive integers n , $P(n)=(n+1)^{n-1}$.

I am not sure how to make use of these results and the approach of this problem. Can someone direct an approach? Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is from the $1997$ argentinian mathematical olympiad.

Here is a solution from [Pablo Soberon's book](https://www.amazon.com.mx/Problem-Solving-Methods-Combinatorics-Approach-Olympiad/dp/3034805969).

The idea is to instead consider $n+1$ parking spots which are placed in a circle (in increasing order) and allow any possible function. Then each function manages to park every car (since the positions are now in a circle a car can go back to the start ). The functions that we want are the ones that leave the position $n+1$ empty.

Consider the equivalence relation in which two functions $f$ and $g$ are the same if  there is $k$ such that $f(i) = g(i) +k\bmod n+1$.

This equivalence relation splits all the possible functions into classes of size $n+1$ in which each member leaves a different position empty (because adding $k$ to each value also adds $k$ to the spot that is empty at the end).

It follows exactly one of each $n+1$ of the functions leave position $n+1$ empty.

Since there are $(n+1)^n$ in total the answer is $(n+1)^{n-1}$